# How to get only odd numbers in array and square them using numpy for python?

Tags: python, numpy, modulo

I've done this without NumPy in Python:

```
def fun_list(list_, x):
#set list to odd numbers in list_ raised to number x
s=[]    
s= [i**x for i in list_ if (i%2)!=0]
list_=s          
print(list_)
```

Testing the function:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
print(fun_list(list1, 2))
print(fun_list(list2, 3))
```

Results:

```
[1, 9]
None
[27, 125]
None
```

NOW need to do it using NumPy, which I don't understand and can't find much about it online and what I find doesn't make sense to me.  This is what I've tried:

```
import math 
#set list to odd numbers in list_ raised to number x
a=np.array([array_])
pwr=x
a=np.array([a if np.mod(a)!=0])
a=np.array([np.power(a,pwr)])
print (a)
```

Testing the function:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
array2 = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])
print(fun_array(array1, 2))
print(fun_array(array2, 3))
```

Results:

```
File "<ipython-input-161-fc4f5193f204>", line 21
a=np.array([a if np.mod(a)!=0])
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not understanding what to do to get only the odd numbers in the array using NumPy.

Comment: Indent your function properly please. Python is very whitespace sensitive.

Comment: How about educating me as to how you see it should be please?  I haven't received any errors how I have it. Thanks!

Comment: If I paste your first snippet into my console, I get an indentation error. Consider indenting all your code by 4 spaces, not just the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
power = 2
answer = (a[a%2==1])**power
print (answer)
```

**Output**

```
[ 1  9 25]
```

Here, the operation `a%2==1` returns a Boolean array `array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)` which is `True` if the remainder/modulus after dividing by `2` (which is given by `a%2`) value is `1` and `False` if its `0`. Using this as an argument for your array `a` will return only the `a` values for which the argument is 'True'. This yields only odd numbers from `a`. The `**` then squares these odd numbers. In case you want the even numbers, one way would be to put `a%2==0` in your condition.

Comment: OP is clearly a beginner who is working hard. Please explain your code instead of just handing over an undocumented solution.

Comment: OP might be a beginner but not naive enough not to be able to break down the code (as concise as the answer) line by line to see the output. Sorry but I don't believe in spoon feeding. Except `a%2==1` which returns a boolean array, I don't see anything worth clarifying. And OP seems to be aware of `%` and `==`

Comment: My point is that what you're doing is the worst kind of spoon feeding. Giving a block of undocumented but working code is a great way to get someone to stop asking questions and just copy and paste.

Comment: Even if you don't explain the what, it's very important to explain the why in my opinion. No one can read your mind. They can only see what you did.

Comment: I agree that I could have added a small explanation in the spirit of a beginner but then writing "using NumPy, which I don't understand and can't find much about it online" is something which is impossible to digest *at least* today. But anyway, I'll keep it in mind for the next time

Comment: @Bazingaa why would you "keep it in mind for the next time"? You can still edit your answer...

Comment: In case you down voted because of missing explanation, the explanation now should revert it

Comment: Vote reverted. I didn't catch the part about being unable to find documentation online. I'll give the benefit of the doubt though and say it's poor phrasing. It's not that they're isn't a lot of documentation, it's just that must of it is not remotely beginner level.

Comment: The part is still in the question in case you missed it initially. Anyway, it's all water under the bridge now

Answer (score 1):

The power of numpy is that it allows you to operate on entire array in a single operation. This is called vectorization or vectorizing. Under the hood there are loops to do this of course, but they are written in the C language and highly optimized so they run orders of magnitude faster than anything you can achieve with pure python.

So when you write a function using numpy, your number one goal is to have numpy do all the work. Ideally there should be no explicit loops, only calls that operate on entire arrays all at once. Fortunately, numpy provides all the necessary utilities to make this possible in your case.

Here is a step by step guide then:

First, convert your input into an array. Arrays are just like lists in many ways, with the difference that you can do vectorized operations on them. Most numpy functions will silently convert their inputs to an array if you pass in a list, but we will do it explicitly:

```
def numpy_fun_list(list_, x):
    arr = np.array(list_)
```

So far so good. All further operations will be done to `arr` instead of `list_`.

Next you'll want to filter out the even elements. The easiest way to do this is by masking the array.  When you index a numpy array with a Boolean array of the same size, it will select the elements that are True in the Boolean array and discard the rest. For example:

```
>>> data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> mask = np.narray([True, False, False, True])
>>> data[mask]
array([1, 4])
```

All the conditional and comparison operators create such Boolean arrays. In your case, you want to check if a number is odd, so you use modulo just like in Python, except that modulo operates on each element of the array:

```
    mask = (arr % 2) == 1
```

The operator `==` is what turns the result of the modulo operation into a Boolean mask:

```
    arr = arr[mask]
```

Now we need to raise each element of the remaining `arr` to the power `x`. As you guessed, that's what `np.power` does:

```
    arr = np.power(arr, x)
```

That's it. Now you can return or print your result. Actually, a little note about that:

Your original function prints the result to the screen but doesn't return it. The return value of the function is implicitly `None`, which is why you see all those Nones printed. If you don't return it, there's not much you can do with the computed list, making the whole function fairly useless. My recommendation is to replace `print (list_)` with `return list_`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this mask thing.  I get the concept, but I technically don't know the values in the array before it is run, so can't manually do what you have here.  I need a where statement I think.  I found this, but I am not implementing it correctly.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html.  
    ` import math 
     import numpy.ma as ma
     a=np.array([array_])
     pwr=x
     ma.masked_where(a%2!=0, True)
     ma.masked_where(a%2==0, False)
      a=np.power(a,pwr)
      return (a)`

Comment: @JenniferCrosby. You're going way too complicated. Masks are brilliantly simple once you figure out how they work, and in my experience, you don't need functions like `where` to apply them most of the time. Look at my example with the `>>>`, and then remember that `(arr % 2) == 1` is a boolean mask that selects odd elements from `arr`. If you just do `arr[mask]`, you end up with an array containing only the elements that are odd, because that's how you made the mask. Work through every step. First look at `arr % 2`, then `(arr % 2) == 1`, then `arr[(arr % 2) == 1]`.

Comment: If you combine all the indented lines in my code (not including the ones with `>>>`, you will get the exact function you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np
def my_fun(a):
arr_1=np.array(a)
print(arr_1)

```
## even and odd elements fetching in two diff matrix
[l,b]=np.shape(arr_1)
print(l,b)
for key1 in range(0,l):
    for key2 in range(0,b):
        if arr_1[key1,key2]%2==0:
            idx_div_zero=([key1,key2])
            prop_format=tuple(idx_div_zero)
            arr_1[prop_format]=0
        if arr_1[key1,key2]%2!=0:
            ff=([key1,key2])
            prop_fmt_nz=tuple(ff)
            arr_1[prop_fmt_nz]=1
print(arr_1)
```