# Converting predefined 2d Array into 2d bool array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I am given a predefined array

```
a = [[2 3 4]
     [5 6 7]
     [8 9 10]]
```

my issue is converting this array into a boolean array where all even numbers are true. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy, and it's pretty straightforward:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10]]
a = np.asarray(a)
(a % 2) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows using Numpy:

> ```
> import numpy as np
> a = [[2, 3, 4],
>      [5, 6, 7],
>      [8, 9, 10]]
> aBool=(np.asarray(a)%2==0)
> ```

The variable aBool will contain True where there is an Even value and False for an Odd value.

> ```
> array([[ True, False,  True],
>        [False,  True, False],
>        [ True, False,  True]])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617421/how-to-get-only-odd-numbers-in-array-and-square-them-using-numpy-for-python):

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

answer = (a[a%2==0])
print(answer)
```

which is essentially what [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6699875/andrew) said but without using NumPy

If you're interested in getting booleans and testing for certain conditions within a NumPy array you can find a neat post [here](https://www.python-course.eu/numpy_masking.php)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply using one line (if you don't want to use numpy):

```
[[i % 2 == 0 for i in sublist] for sublist in a]

>>> [[True, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, True]]
```

Here, `i % 2` denotes the modulus operator, which gives the remainder when the first number is divided by the second. In this case, for even numbers `i % 2 = 0`, and for odd numbers `i % 2 = 1`. The two = signs means that the expression is evaluated as a boolean.

The two `for` loops iterate over each list inside of the 2D list.

This can be extended if you find this format easier to understand, but it essentially does the same thing:

```
>>> newlist = []
>>> for sublist in a:
        partial_list = []
        for i in sublist:
                partial_list.append(i % 2 == 0)
        newlist.append(partial_list)


>>> newlist
[[True, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to mention negations:

```
a = [[2, 3, 4],
     [5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10]]

>>> ~np.array(a)%2
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

This is a boolean form:

```
>>> ~(np.array(a)%2).astype(bool)
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```